# Format XML output with apache commons configuration XMLConfiguration

Tags: java, xml-serialization, apache-commons-config

I am using the apache commons configuration XMLConfiguration to build and save an XML file.
When saving there is no formatting.
I get something like:

```
<root>
<node>
<child>
</child>
</node>
</root>
```

I know there are plenty of ways to use some other library to take that output and format it, but surely there must be a way to set something as simple as indention from commons configuration?

Answer (score 10):

Encountered the same issue. Although the question was asked long time ago, would like to share a solution :

XMLConfiguration class has a protected method called createTransformed. It should be extended and set by [right configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384802/java-how-to-indent-xml-generated-by-transformer) for indentation.

```
public class ExtendedXMLConfiguration extends XMLConfiguration
{
    public ExtendedXMLConfiguration(File file) throws ConfigurationException
    {
        super(file);
    }

    @Override
    protected Transformer createTransformer() throws TransformerException {
        Transformer transformer = super.createTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
        return transformer;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the constructor.
The createTransformer in XMLConfiguration sets the Indent to "yes" but the indent-amount was missing.