# XML returned from URL not being parsed correctly

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

The XML returned from URL : 'http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/data_index?sha1=ba24d5de831911b684c92cd289ed5ff826271824' is not being parsed correctly using this code :

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    try {

        String urlString = "http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/data_index?sha1=ba24d5de831911b684c92cd289ed5ff826271824";
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new URL(urlString).openStream());

        System.out.println("Doc is : "+doc);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The doc value being outputted is 'Doc is : [#document: null]' Also, no exceptions are being thrown.
Navigating directly to the URL seems to produce valid XML. Is there something wrong with the code ?

Comment: It seems you are not getting any response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc is problably being built correctly, but you are expecting `Document`s `toString()` method to output the XML content, which it doesn't. Have a look at using a [`Transformer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html) to output the XML.

Comment: Thanks! this link also helped - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384802/java-how-to-indent-xml-generated-by-transformer

Answer (score 1):

There is not necessarily anything wrong with the code; I took a working program that is very similar, and printed out the doc object and got the same output.