# jdbc export data into xml

Tags: java, sql, xml, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: How to Indent XML Generated by Transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384802/java-how-to-indent-xml-generated-by-transformer)
>   [jdbc export to xml - declaration showing standalone = no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445031/jdbc-export-to-xml-declaration-showing-standalone-no)

```
      TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
      Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
      String outputPathname = "output.xml";
      StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(outputPathname));
      Source source = new DOMSource(dataDoc);
      transformer.transform(source, result);
```

I need to use jdbc to export data into a specific structured xml document. I'm using the parsing approach. I need the top to show

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
```

However, the file create actually shows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>.
```

How can I modify the code to achieve the desired form?

Comment: It's actually *better* to have this `encoding` attribute.

Comment: You are right but it's a requirement to follow the specified structure..how can i set standalone to be yes?

Comment: @jtahlborn this is not a duplicate as this asks read the xml declaration the other asks how to indent xml

Comment: How you generate xml using jdbc and what is parsing approach? What magic is this?