# JAVA 8 xml pretty output not working properly

Tags: java, xml

I try to save Document to the XML in pretty output. But problem is every new element start from line of pervious element end tag.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><report>
<jiraentry category="SERVICE &amp; ASSET" component="DOCMAN" priority="10" summary="Bug Generated By, UNCHECKED_ACCESS">Tool:UNCHECKED_ACCESS Date:2015-11-12
</jiraentry>
```

You can see that  and text in  print in pervious line.Here is the below my Java code which i used to save xml by using transformer.

```
         //normalize the xml file
         root.getDocumentElement().normalize();
         //remove standalone no
         root.setXmlStandalone(true);

         // write the content into xml file
         TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
         transformerFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", new Integer(0));//add intend to the new line

         Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
         transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

         DOMSource source = new DOMSource(root);
         StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(this.outpath), "UTF-8"));//save the file
         transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Any one can suggest me to make this more pretty and clear.

Comment: does your original xml contain linebreaks?

Comment: Their no thing calls original xml, program creates the xml by transforming the root.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the indent amount for the transformer as shown in the snippet below:

`t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
t.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");`

Useful Reference: [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384802/java-how-to-indent-xml-generated-by-transformer)

Comment: No lucky still the same