# How to remove #text from my Node parsing in Java dom xml parsing

Tags: java, xml, dom, text

So I have the following code which I pretty much copied from  [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/UseDOMparsertodealwithXMLdocumentwithattributes.htm).  But the problem is my text nodes do not contain any text they just have attributes.  So I have like

```
<Random name="Katie" num="5"></Random>
```

and I'm using this code to parse it:

```
  private void listNodes(Node node, String indent)
  {
    String nodeName = node.getNodeName();
    System.out.println(indent + " Node is: " + nodeName);
    
    if(node instanceof Element && node.hasAttributes())
    {
      System.out.println(indent + "Attributes are: ");
      NamedNodeMap attrs = node.getAttributes();
      for (int i = 0; i < attrs.getLength(); i++) 
      {
        Attr attribute = (Attr) attrs.item(i);
        System.out.println(indent + attribute.getName() + "=" + attribute.getValue());
      }
    }
    
    NodeList list = node.getChildNodes(); 
    
    if (list.getLength() > 0) 
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++)
      {
        listNodes(list.item(i), indent + " "); 
      } 
    }
  }
```

For some reason my empty text nodes all say

> Node is: #text

Does anyone know how to skip empty node text when parsing the xml file?

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: You may also remove all empty text nodes:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16285664/1812434

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With DTD validation you can have the parser automatically suppress the whitespace between elements.  However to modify your specific implementation, you can test for Text nodes, and ignore them if they are empty.

```
private void listNodes(Node node, String indent)
{
    if (node instanceof Text) {
        String value = node.getNodeValue().trim();
        if (value.equals("") ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    String nodeName = node.getNodeName();
    System.out.println(indent + " Node is: " + nodeName);
    ...
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `Node.getNodeType()` method for this purpose:

```
Node node;
if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
   // Your code inside this
}
```

Answer (score 5):

'#text' is the result of invoking getNodeName() method on empty node.These empty nodes can be identified using 'XPath' and can be removed.

```
XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
// XPath to find empty text nodes.
XPathExpression xpathExp = xpathFactory.newXPath().compile(
    "//text()[normalize-space(.) = '']");  
NodeList emptyTextNodes = (NodeList) 
    xpathExp.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
// Remove each empty text node from document.
for (int i = 0; i < emptyTextNodes.getLength(); i++) {
  Node emptyTextNode = emptyTextNodes.item(i);
emptyTextNode.getParentNode().removeChild(emptyTextNode);
}
```

'#text' is generated as a result of empty spaces.